# Error occurred during batch insert (you can disable batch insert in order to skip particular rows)

Tags: sql, database, import-from-excel

Reason:

> SQL Error [42701]: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO public.customer_master (id,customer_id,primary_card_open_date,primary_card_expiration_date,member_number,program_identification_value,promotional_code,stakeholder_id,sub_program_identification_value,pseudo_dda_number,linked_account,cip_id,source_refferal,source_refferal_identifier,external_reference_id,ssrp_file_date,is_risk_detected,hubspot_contact_id,microloan_elig_date,is_eligible_for_supl_point,updated_unit21,created_by,created_at,updated_by,updated_at,onb_customer_id_onb_customer,source_refferal,source_refferal_identifier)
> VALUES (117873,'4.38E+17','2021-02-22 -06','2026-03-31 -06','','FC0322','','StakHolder','4.38E+17','7.13E+12','','','','','','2022-06-26 -06','FALSE','','2021-05-02 -06','FALSE','TRUE','system','2021-09-09 00:00:00-06','system','2022-06-26 00:00:00-06','4.38E+17','','') was aborted: ERROR: column "source_refferal" specified more than once
> Position: 503  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.

Comment: True - so don't know how we can help - suggest you add table definition and expected outcome.

Comment: You have both a `MySQL` and a `Postgresql` tag and no indication of which database you are actually using. Confine the question to a single database. Also indicate the database version, the client used and the OS used.

Comment: actually I'm importing csv file into Table and getting this error

Comment: It would help if you edit your question to describe in what context you are encountering this error. What database, what is the command you are running, what are you trying to achieve? This guide will help you get useful responses: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code tidied up so that you can see the problem

```
INSERT INTO public.customer_master 
(id,customer_id,primary_card_open_date,primary_card_expiration_date,
member_number,program_identification_value,promotional_code,
stakeholder_id,sub_program_identification_value,pseudo_dda_number,
linked_account,cip_id,

source_refferal,
source_refferal_identifier,

external_reference_id,ssrp_file_date,is_risk_detected,
hubspot_contact_id,microloan_elig_date,is_eligible_for_supl_point,
updated_unit21,created_by,created_at,updated_by,updated_at,
onb_customer_id_onb_customer,

source_refferal,
source_refferal_identifier) 
VALUES 
(117873,'4.38E+17','2021-02-22 -06','2026-03-31 -06','','FC0322','','StakHolder',
'4.38E+17','7.13E+12','','','','','','2022-06-26 -06','FALSE','','2021-05-02 -06',
'FALSE','TRUE','system','2021-09-09 00:00:00-06','system','2022-06-26 00:00:00-06','4.38E+17','','')
```